# Impossible to deploy on Heroku

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, npm, nuxt.js

I'm trying to deploy this application, made with Nuxt.js, on Heroku online in universal mode. 
The steps I have performed are: "npm run build" and "npm run start" for headings that all worked well in production mode.

Then:

```
heroku create
heroku config: set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION = false
heroku config: set HOST = 0.0.0.0
heroku config: set NODE_ENV = production
```

Then I added to my file 'package.json': 
   `heroku-postbuild": "npm run build`

I created a Procfile with: `web: npm run start`

And when I do: `git push heroku master` i have this error:

```
remote:  FATAL  Nuxt Build Error
remote: 
remote:   at WebpackBundler.webpackCompile (node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/dist/webpack.js:5367:13)
remote:   at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:86:5)
remote: 
remote: tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
remote: 
remote:    ╭─────────────────────────────╮
remote:    │                             │
remote:    │   ✖ Nuxt Fatal Error        │
remote:    │                             │
remote:    │   Error: Nuxt Build Error   │
remote:    │                             │
remote:    ╰─────────────────────────────╯
remote: 
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR! errno 1
remote: npm ERR! MyMovieApp@1.0.0 build: `nuxt build`
remote: npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote: npm ERR! 
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the MyMovieApp@1.0.0 build script.
remote: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote: 
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.CynTY/_logs/2019-07-09T20_01_04_895Z-debug.log
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR! errno 1
remote: npm ERR! MyMovieApp@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild: `npm run build`
remote: npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote: npm ERR! 
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the MyMovieApp@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild script.
remote: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote: 
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.CynTY/_logs/2019-07-09T20_01_04_915Z-debug.log
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:        
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:        
remote:        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
remote:        https://help.heroku.com/
remote:        
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:        
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to movie-app-luglio2019.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/movie-app-luglio2019.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/movie-app-luglio2019.git'

remote:  FATAL  Nuxt Build Error
remote: 
remote:   at WebpackBundler.webpackCompile (node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/dist/webpack.js:5367:13)
remote:   at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:86:5)
remote: 
remote: tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
remote: 
remote:    ╭─────────────────────────────╮
remote:    │                             │
remote:    │   ✖ Nuxt Fatal Error        │
remote:    │                             │
remote:    │   Error: Nuxt Build Error   │
remote:    │                             │
remote:    ╰─────────────────────────────╯
remote: 
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR! errno 1
remote: npm ERR! MyMovieApp@1.0.0 build: `nuxt build`
remote: npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote: npm ERR! 
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the MyMovieApp@1.0.0 build script.
remote: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote: 
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.CynTY/_logs/2019-07-09T20_01_04_895Z-debug.log
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR! errno 1
remote: npm ERR! MyMovieApp@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild: `npm run build`
remote: npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote: npm ERR! 
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the MyMovieApp@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild script.
remote: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote: 
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.CynTY/_logs/2019-07-09T20_01_04_915Z-debug.log
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:        
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:        
remote:        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
remote:        https://help.heroku.com/
remote:        
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:        
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to movie-app-luglio2019.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/movie-app-luglio2019.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/movie-app-luglio2019.git'
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you don't have a terminal name or $TERM that heroku is happy with. You can confirm if this is the case by typing this into your terminal emulator:

`echo $TERM`

If things are all ok, you will get something like this back:

`xterm-256color`

but I suspect you'll get "unknown" or "undefined" or something. You will need to look on googlepedia to get instructions to check and set the configuration for whatever terminal application you are using.

Comment: the result, from the command `echo $TERM ` is `xterm-256color `

Comment: Maybe not that then. I presume your package.json from the question is a typo and actually says: `"heroku-postbuild": "npm run build"`. You could delete node modules and run `npm install --production`.